# How does nlohmann::json implement the nice deserialization syntax?

Tags: c++, c++11, nlohmann-json

How nlohmann::json implement the nice deserialization syntax?

```
// You can create an object (deserialization) by appending _json to a string literal.

//create object from string literal
json j = "{ \"happy\": true, \"pi\": 3.141 }"_json;

// or even nicer with a raw string literal
auto j2 = R"(
{
    "happy": true,
    "pi": 3.141
}
)"_json;
```

Grammally it seems wrong. But it indeed works. Any tricks here?

Comment: This is [user-defined literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal)

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Never heard it before.

Comment: Real programmers use `_cpp` literals.